# How to fix vss scroll bar?

Tags: html, css

I used this in a css for my ProfileServlet:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical {
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button:horizontal {
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}
```

Notice in the image below only 2 of the 4 scroll bar buttons look correct:

[image]

How could i get all 4 buttons to look correct?

Also How do I make the scrollbar-thumb visible?

Why aren't the horizontal and vertical scroll bars the same shape

Comment: I wont do that, other browsers wont support this styles. If it's neccesary i would do it with jquery scripts: http://slodive.com/web-development/jquery-scroll/

Comment: I haven't heard much good from JQuery

Comment: Then this might help you: http://xeemez.blogspot.de/2013/09/changing-style-of-scrollbar-with-css.html

Comment: There is no consistent way to control scrollbar using pure CSS on all browsers.  If you want reliable cross-browser control over the scrollbar appearance use JS (one very popular plugin is [jScrollPane](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/))

Answer (score 0):

Well I discovered the answer to number 1 and 3. 1:

change:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical {
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button:horizontal {
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}
```

To:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:end {
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button:horizontal:end {
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:start {
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button:horizontal:start {
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
}
```

2:

I had :

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 15px;
}
```

But needed:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
}
```

Now just need scrollbar-thumb to be visible.